# IFAND rule in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to work in excel using IFAND rule to try and build the following logic however I am unsuccessful until now.

```
Department   Date        Customer

Digital      11/02/19    Customer A
Voice        14/02/19    Customer A
```

What I am trying to achieve is that, if customer A contacted us through a `dept = digital` and after voice it will return 1.

Can someone help please?

```
=if(and(A:A="Digital",B:B>b2,C:C=C2,A:A="Voice"),true,false)
```

This is the logic we have used so far.

Thanks!

Comment: That will result in false in all cases, you check as the first argument of AND() col A being "Digital" and then the last argument of AND() if Col A is "Voice" - any one line cannot be both.

Comment: So would both lines be `True` or only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming data is sorted on *Customer* and *Date*, then try:

```
=AND(C2=C3,A2="Digital",A3="Voice")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Sumproduct,

```
=IF(A4="Voice",SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$4>B4)*1,($C$3:$C$4=C4)*1,($A$3:$A$4="Digital")*1),0)
```

it allows you to assign a 1 for each row that meets the various criteria and then times all 3 criteria's resulting integers together

- Criteria 1: Is column B greater than Date?
- Criteria 2: Is column C = Customer
- Criteria 3: Is column A = Voice

If all criteria are met for the row then

1x1x1 = 1

If any criteria arent met then the result is 0

```
0x1x0 = 0,
1x0x0 = 0,
0x0x0 = 0,
0x0x1 = 0,
etc, etc
```